# Couchbase Repository BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Hi Please could someone assist. I am getting a BeanCreationException during the loading of my application context. I am trying to load the following bean:

```
package org.stevie.spring.test.webmvc.household;

import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.stevie.spring.test.webmvc.domain.Household;

@Repository
public interface HouseholdRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Household, String> {

}
```

The console gives me the log message: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

I am loading another repository bean which works fine:

```
package org.stevie.spring.test.webmvc.member;

import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.stevie.spring.test.webmvc.domain.Member;

@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Member, String> {

}
```

The faulty bean is being detected in the component scan but spring framework can't instantiate it. Thanks for your help.

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'householdRepository' defined in org.stevie.spring.test.webmvc.household.HouseholdRepository defined in @EnableCouchbaseRepositories declared on CouchbaseConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$171/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.stevie.spring.test.webmvc.SpringTestDriveWebmvcApplication.main(SpringTestDriveWebmvcApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.BasicCouchbasePersistentProperty.getFieldName(BasicCouchbasePersistentProperty.java:78) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.BasicCouchbasePersistentProperty.isIdProperty(BasicCouchbasePersistentProperty.java:103) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.BasicCouchbasePersistentEntity.returnPropertyIfBetterIdPropertyCandidateOrNull(BasicCouchbasePersistentEntity.java:72) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.BasicCouchbasePersistentEntity.returnPropertyIfBetterIdPropertyCandidateOrNull(BasicCouchbasePersistentEntity.java:39) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.addPersistentProperty(BasicPersistentEntity.java:218) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:552) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator$$Lambda$977/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1766) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:487) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:239) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator$$Lambda$971/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4872) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:295) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport$$Lambda$903/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:176) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:295) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.CouchbaseRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CouchbaseRepositoryFactoryBean.java:89) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the full stack trace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: i've posted my stack trace